# MYSQL IN on 2 columns?

Tags: sql, mysql

Is it possible to do smthng like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x1,x2 IN (values)`?

Comment: no, something like ? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x1 IN (values) or x2 in(values);`

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE x1 IN (values) and/or x2 IN (values) - not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need matching in pairs:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (x1, x2) IN ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

will match only `1, 2` or `3, 4`

If you need cross-matches:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   x1 IN (1, 3)
        AND x2 IN (2, 4)
```

will match any of the `1, 2`, `3, 2`, `1, 4` or `3, 4`

Comment: +1 Didn't know you could do a paired match with that syntax. Much neater that way.

Comment: +1 for the pair matching (I couldn't find docs for it, but trying it: `SELECT (1, 3) IN ((1, 2), (3, 4));` only matches the pairs...  (1,2) or (3,4).   Not bad...

Comment: nice feature, but unfortunately, its not what i needed exactly, but i managed it with this :D

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that's possible - you simply have to either state...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (x1 IN (values) OR x2 IN (values)) ..
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (x1 IN (values) AND x2 IN (values)) ..
```

...depending on the logic you require.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (x1,x2) IN ((value1,value2), (value3,value4));
```

You can even do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (x1,x2) IN (SELECT x3,x4 FROM another_table);
```

Of course, x3, x4 have to match the data type of x1, x2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you mean it, you'd have to write

```
... WHERE x1 IN (values) AND x2 IN (values)
... WHERE x1 IN (values) OR  x2 IN (values)
```

But you'll have to duplicate the values list